# Using net user with a system account with a backslash

Tags: command-line, active-directory, escaping

Entering:

`net user "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool"`

Results in:

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
         username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]
```

Why? Do I have to escape the backslash character? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the ` \ ` by doing ` \\ ` instead?

Comment: Yes, escaping the backslash with another backslash returns the same error.

Comment: ...I have also tried escaping using the caret character `^`, without success

Comment: IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool is not actually a user, but a reference to the abstract AppPoolIdentity, so I don;t think it will work for this. what exactly are you trying to do to it with net user? I've seen that some people have to create a SQL user with this identity, or use iacls/cacls to grant file permissions, but I'm not seeing anyone use it with 'net user'.

Comment: BTW, if you could use 'net user' for this purpose, the syntax would be 'net user "DefaultAppPool" /DOMAIN:"IIS APPPOOL" /times:ALL' (substitute '/times:ALL' for whatever net user command you want to run)

Comment: I am investigating a problem that started suddenly yesterday whereby when running as this user, the app pool has trouble querying an AD server. Changing the apppool to run as NetworkService, fixes things, but I understand running as DefaultAppPool is best practise.